# Sending extra information to scenekit shader?

Tags: ios, shader, scenekit

I am using Scenekit shader modifier, is it possible to send extra information for every vertices like timestamp or some data?
So in the shader modifier i can use those values and discard vertices (mainly for animation)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. See protocol [SCNShadable](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnshadable#1654834) documentation. That documentation has a sample that sounds very close to what you're asking for. There's also a uniform (`u_time`) for timestamp.